# How to add a sound to Android pico TTS engine?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I'm using the pico default android TTS engine with IPA caracters doing this

```
String text3 = "<speak xml:lang=\"fr-FR\"> <phoneme alphabet=\"ipa\" ph=\"+"+words+"\"/>.</speak>";
        myTTS.speak(text3, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
```

It's generally working, but for some letters it doesn't like "ã" or "ɑ" etc.

So my question is, How can I add theses letters/sounds, to this TTS engine ?

Comment: Why are you using IPA characters? French is natively supported by Pico TTS.

Comment: Because I'm looking for a IPA TTS, not french

Comment: Hmmm... then why are you setting French as an input language?

Comment: Because I have to select a default language to pick a voice

Comment: OK. Did you try to set different language? E.g., English or Spanish?

Comment: I did, when I put English, I have only english sound like "ðə" for "the", but I lost all french sounds like "ʁ". Because the english sounds of the english voice doesn't have them. So I'd like to, first, at the missing and wrong sound in french, secondly, merge french and english in 1 voice.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can use `addEarcon()` to add sounds to **testToSpeech** [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html).
This medthod is used to add earcons.It will link a text to a speecific sound file.
You can also find example on this.

```
mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, new OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            mTts.addEarcon("[tock]", "com.ideal.itemid", R.raw.tock_snd);
            showRecordingView();
        }
    });
```

There is also a very good explanation on addEarcon in book **Professional Android Sensor Programming** by Greg Milette, Adam Stroud
at page no 366 and 367.

You can also find example on this [link](https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib/blob/master/app/src/root/gast/playground/speech/tts/TextToSpeechDemo.java).

Comment: Would not this require adding/having sound files for each IPA character?

Comment: Yup if you want to have a custom sound for each string.

Comment: It would be more for every syllable no ? Because If I have the sound "a" and "t" , the "ta" would sound like "t-a".

Comment: Not exactly, because I don't want to play earcon, but only myTTS.speak, and if I use the addSpeech it won't work because my input is a SSML string. I need to add the sound into the TTS engine during the phonetic transcription part.

Comment: k I thought you wanted to add a speech for specific string.